# How to zip multiple datasets from different folders in one zip file SAS

Tags: loops, sas, macros, php-ziparchive

I have a macro that creates a zip file to archive all datasets from ONE folder. I would also like to also include only a few datasets from a different folder into that same zip file, if possible?

I'm using an already built out macro call 'zip(path, zip name, ziplock);' which will create a zip file from a folder. How can I add other datasets from another folder in that zip file without moving the datasets into that folder manually after.

```
The macro parameters are defined below:
path = file path of directory to be zipped
zip name = name of new zip file
ziplock = location of new zip file
```

I would like to zip an entire folder AND a few datasets from another folder

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell you without seeing the macro contents.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to answer for *your* macro without seeing the macro, but there are ways to zip files in SAS, and here's one.

https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/03/04/add-files-to-a-zip-archive-with-filename-zip/

Basically, you use a filename to the zip file:

```
filename zipfile "\\path\to\zipfile.zip";
```

Then you make a specific filename to the *member* inside the zipfile:

```
filename newfile zip "\\path\to\zipfile.zip" member="path\to\sasfile.sas7bdat";
```

Then you use byte-wise streaming to copy the file in.  From the above post with minor edits:

```
data _null_;
    infile data_fn recfm=n;
    file newfile recfm=n;
    input byte $char1. @;
    put  byte $char1. @;
run;
```

`data_fn` is the actual physical filename of the sas dataset you are adding.

This works fine with files from different folders, so you can easily use this for whatever you want.

Comment: thank you! the second statement is creating a zip file? I won't have an already existing zip file.

Comment: The first statement creates (ish) the zip file, then the second statement creates (ish) the member in the zip file.  (I don't think it's _actually_ created until something is written to it, but it creates the handle, and then the file will be created).  It assumes it does not already exist (the code in the blog goes into how to delete it in the event it already exists).

Comment: ok, I have like 20 datasets to add to a zip file. Is this method adding one data set at a time?

Comment: Yep - you can just do the 'add' part 20 times.  Fairly straightforward.

Comment: the "member" part 20 times? will I need to repeat the data _null_ step as well?

Comment: Yes, the add part would be the "member" (which defines the inside filename) and the `data _null_` step which actually copies over the file.

Comment: oh thank you! is it possible to put both steps in a macro and can run through the datasets I would like copied to the zip file?

Comment: Of course, a macro would be how I'd do it.